# Simplify code to get min, max and exact value according to position

Tags: java, android

***case1***
**Input**
8
**Output**
min=0
max=9
exact=8

***case2*

Input**
27
**Output**
min=20
max=29
exact=7

```
    double doubleValue = (double) position / 10;
                int intValue = position / 10;
                int exactPosition = position % 10;
                int maxValue = 0;
                int minValue = 0;

                if(doubleValue > intValue)
                {
                    maxValue = (10 * (intValue + 1)) - 1;
                    minValue = 10 * intValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(intValue == 0)
                    {
                        maxValue = (10 * 1) - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        maxValue = (10 * intValue) - 1;
                    }

                    minValue = 10 * intValue;
                    if(maxValue < minValue)
                    {
                        maxValue = maxValue + 10;
                    }
               }
```

This is working fine. Now I would like to optimise it into a short code as I feel its currently uses to many conditions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better fit for a good code (with better formatting); for bad code, problem should be stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one,

```
    int intValue = position / 10;
    int exactPosition = position % 10;
    int minValue = intValue * 10;
    int maxValue = intValue * 10 + 9;
    System.out.print("MinValue" + minValue + ":MaxValue:" + maxValue + "exactPosition" + exactPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by understanding the conditions:

For a given position, we need to find the minValue and maxValue.
Lets represent the input and output as:

> position -> [minValue, maxValue]

Thus, some examples are :

```
25 -> [21, 30]
31 -> [31, 40]
30 -> [21, 30]
22 -> [21, 30]
```

With some math, we could see that if we do position-1, the problem boils down to finding out the tens digit.

eg:

```
21 - 1 = 20 
30 - 1 = 29
```

We want that both 21 and 30 should have the same range. We see that both 21 and 30 when subtracted one from, have the same tens digit = 2

Thus we could build their minValue and maxValue from this digit 2 as :
minValue = 2*10 +1 = 21
maxValue = (2+1) *10 = 30

Here's the code:

```
int tens = (position-1)/10;
minValue = tens*10 +1;
maxValue = (tens+1)*10;
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation would go a long way to understanding how you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the edge cases here is the logic that you are looking for.

```
int intValue = position / 10;
int minValue = intValue * 10 + 1;
int maxValue = intValue * 10 + 9;
System.out.print("MinValue"+minValue + ":MaxValue:" + maxValue);
```